# pyrosm/geopandas error when calling get_network(network_type='driving')

Tags: python, geopandas, osm.pbf

I'm trying to get the street network from a pbf-file. The very weird is: my script did work initially, so I did transform the exact same pbf data files.  But suddenly my script doesnt't work anymore.

So when I run this code snippet on a pbf-file ('f'), (which is downloaded from OSM):

```
osm = pyrosm.OSM(f)
area = osm.get_network(network_type="driving")
```

I get the error you can see below.
Any ideas what I can do?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 38
     35     os.makedirs(mypath_shp)
     37 osm = pyrosm.OSM(f)
---> 38 area = osm.get_network(network_type="driving")
     39 print("Created network - OK")
     41 # subset = subsetting(area)
     42 # print("Created subset - OK")
     43 
   (...)
     53 # subset.to_file(path_shape, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
     54 # print(" Shapefile - OK")

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\pyrosm\pyrosm.py:205, in OSM.get_network(self, network_type, extra_attributes, nodes)
    202     self._read_pbf()
    204 # Filter network data with given filter
--> 205 edges, node_gdf = get_network_data(
    206     self._node_coordinates,
    207     self._way_records,
    208     tags_as_columns,
    209     network_filter,
    210     self.bounding_box,
    211     slice_to_segments=nodes,
    212 )
    214 if edges is not None:
    215     # Add metadata
    216     edges._metadata.append(network_type)

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\pyrosm\networks.py:37, in get_network_data(node_coordinates, way_records, tags_as_columns, network_filter, bounding_box, slice_to_segments)
     34     return None, None
     36 # Prepare GeoDataFrame
---> 37 edges, nodes = prepare_geodataframe(
     38     nodes,
     39     node_coordinates,
     40     ways,
     41     relations,
     42     relation_ways,
     43     tags_as_columns,
     44     bounding_box,
     45     parse_network=True,
     46     calculate_seg_lengths=slice_to_segments,
     47 )
     49 return edges, nodes

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\pyrosm\frames.pyx:134, in pyrosm.frames.prepare_geodataframe()

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\pyrosm\frames.pyx:141, in pyrosm.frames.prepare_geodataframe()

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\pyrosm\frames.pyx:71, in pyrosm.frames.prepare_way_gdf()

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:188, in GeoDataFrame.__init__(self, data, geometry, crs, *args, **kwargs)
    180     if (
    181         hasattr(geometry, "crs")
    182         and geometry.crs
    183         and crs
    184         and not geometry.crs == crs
    185     ):
    186         raise ValueError(crs_mismatch_error)
--> 188     self.set_geometry(geometry, inplace=True, crs=crs)
    190 if geometry is None and crs:
    191     raise ValueError(
    192         "Assigning CRS to a GeoDataFrame without a geometry column is not "
    193         "supported. Supply geometry using the 'geometry=' keyword argument, "
    194         "or by providing a DataFrame with column name 'geometry'",
    195     )

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:346, in GeoDataFrame.set_geometry(self, col, drop, inplace, crs)
    343     level.crs = crs
    345 # Check that we are using a listlike of geometries
--> 346 level = _ensure_geometry(level, crs=crs)
    347 frame[geo_column_name] = level
    348 frame._geometry_column_name = geo_column_name

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:59, in _ensure_geometry(data, crs)
     57 else:
     58     if isinstance(data, Series):
---> 59         out = from_shapely(np.asarray(data), crs=crs)
     60         return GeoSeries(out, index=data.index, name=data.name)
     61     else:

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py:154, in from_shapely(data, crs)
    138 def from_shapely(data, crs=None):
    139     """
    140     Convert a list or array of shapely objects to a GeometryArray.
    141 
   (...)
    152 
    153     """
--> 154     return GeometryArray(vectorized.from_shapely(data), crs=crs)

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\for_osm\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_vectorized.py:145, in from_shapely(data)
    143         out.append(None)
    144     else:
--> 145         raise TypeError("Input must be valid geometry objects: {0}".format(geom))
    147 if compat.USE_PYGEOS:
    148     return np.array(out, dtype=object)

TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: MULTILINESTRING ((7.646 47.633, 7.646 47.633), (7.646 47.633, 7.646 47.633), (7.646 47.633, 7.646 47.633), (7.646 47.633, 7.646 47.633), (7.646 47.633, 7.647 47.633), (7.647 47.633, 7.647 47.633))
```

Answer (score 0):

With pyrosm 0.6.1. make sure you have Shapely <=1.8.5 and Numpy <=1.23.5 installed.

See also: https://github.com/HTenkanen/pyrosm/issues/212#issuecomment-1422411238

Answer (score 0):

My solution is just a practical solution for which I don't have an explanation: I needed to switch the import for libraries: first pyrosm and then geopandas.

```
import pandas
import pyrosm
import yaml

import os

os.environ["USE_PYGEOS"] = "0"
import geopandas


%load_ext nb_black
```

Then it all worked fine.